# I am getting this error in flutter where the pixels are overflowing .Any solution.Picture of the overflow is attached

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow, pixel

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../providers/orders.dart' as ord;

class OrderItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final ord.OrderItem order;

  OrderItem(this.order);

  @override
  _OrderItemState createState() => _OrderItemState();
}

class _OrderItemState extends State<OrderItem> {
  var _expanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      height:
          _expanded ? min(widget.order.products.length * 20.0 + 150, 300) : 95,
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text('\$${widget.order.amount}'),
              subtitle: Text(
                DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm').format(widget.order.dateTime),
              ),
              trailing: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(_expanded ? Icons.expand_less : Icons.expand_more),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _expanded = !_expanded;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 4),
              height: _expanded
                  ? min(widget.order.products.length * 20.0 + 10, 100)
                  : 0,
              child: ListView(
                children: widget.order.products
                    .map(
                      (prod) => Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            prod.title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '${prod.quantity}x \$${prod.price}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the overflow error,this is a shop app and i am not getting where to modify the code for removing the error  if any solution pls provide it to me and it is showing an overflow error for this flutter code

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MediaQuery to size widgets according to your display dimensions.
You can also try using the Expanded widget or adjust the height property of your AnimatedContainers.